# HTML5 canvas, how to open different hyperlinks by clicking on a different area of the image?

Tags: javascript, c#, html5-canvas, emgucv, image-segmentation

I want to link different web pages based on color of different region.
In image multiple region with same color also points to distinct
   hyperlink
e.g. this is an image with different regions based on color
**please click here to see** [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksUsW.jpg)] is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using image maps.
https://www.html-5-tutorial.com/map-and-area-elements.htm
This is exactly what they are for.

Comment: actually i'm automating a floor plan and every time the plan is different so how to develop an algorithm which automatically detect and create segments based on color where each segment points to a separate link

Comment: Do you know the pixels of the region? If so you need not detect the segments.

Comment: no i didn't know the pixels region i want to write an algorithm that find the region boundary pixels coordinates and define the area tag over that region